# Geographic Information Systems Public/free access to GIS data of mapped underground utilities in Metro Manila

Tags: geospatial

I am really new to GIS, but am currently practicing this new skill via QGIS since its opensource. I am trying to make a map that will showcase known underground utilities such as water lines, fiber optics, telecom lines, drainage, electric lines, etc.. I actually manage to produce some data locations for some of these by manually locating all visibles utilities on site and transferring them thereafter to the software. But I felt lacking at some points and I might miss some important locations that is not visually present.

Can I find some useful source (shapefile,etc) for these utilities in Metro Manila so that I can compare my own set of data and merge them eventually?